# jquery getting a tag of selected option in select

Tags: jquery, tags, html-select

I have searched a lot for a simple thing but I cant find a solution.
How can I get price of selected option in jquery?... suppose

```
<select id="combo">
    <option value="1" price="22">Soap</option>
    <option value="2" price="24">Milk</option>
</select>
```

I know how to get the value and the name... but price?

Thanks in advance..

Thank you.. Solved... In case anybody needs it... how to calculate price discounts in a select...with decimals.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label>Variedad</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="form-control cambio" id="variedad" name="variedad_id">
                <option value="4" data-precio="40.00">Plata</option>
                <option value="1" data-precio="10.00">Oro</option>
                <option value="3" data-precio="30.00">Cobre</option>
                <option value="2" data-precio="20.00">Platino</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <label>Precio Gramo</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <span class="form-control" id="precio">20.00</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <label>Peso</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="form-control cambio" name="peso" type="number" id="peso">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <label>Descuento</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <span class="form-control" id="descuento">0</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <label>Total</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <span class="form-control" id="total">10.00 €</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('select#variedad').on('change', function () {
        var precio = $('option', '#variedad').filter(':selected').data('precio');
        $('span#precio').html( precio );
    });

    $('.cambio').bind( "change keyup", function() {
        var precio = document.getElementById('precio').innerHTML;
        precio = parseFloat(precio);

        var descuento = document.getElementById('descuento').innerHTML;
        descuento = parseFloat(descuento);

        var peso = parseFloat($('input#peso').val());

        var total = (precio*peso) - ( ( ( precio * peso ) * descuento ) / 100 )
        total = (total).toFixed(2);
        $('span#total').html(total + ' €');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('option', '#combo').filter(':selected').attr('price');
```

However, you might want to use data-price as the attribute in which case

```
$('option', '#combo').filter(':selected').data('price');
```

Comment: Thanks Adam... but how to use it?... like this?

$("#combo").on('change', function () {
   var priceVal = $('option','#combo").filter(':selected').data('price').val();
 });

Comment: The code in my answer simpåly returns the price, so yes, put it in a variable and do whatever you want with it!  But looks like you've fixed it from the edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#combo option:selected" ).attr("price");
```

It will retrun  the price.

for ex: if u select the soap in combo box it will retrun the price as "22".